# Excel read values in column then search column in another spreadsheet for those values

Tags: excel, vba

Excuse my wording. I'm using this to keep track of my students attendance. I am using a scanner that inputs the student's IDs into a column on a input spreadsheet. I need a macro to search for those values in another column of another spreadsheet then put an X in the column next to the found ID.

Ex.
Spreadsheet: Input

```
Column A
0001
0002
0003
```

Spreadsheet: Roster

```
Column A Column B Column C
0001     Name     X
0002     Name     X
0003     Name     X
0004     Name
0005     Name
```

Basically, it searches the values in input for the same value in column A of the other spreadsheet then puts a X in column C of the same row

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLOOKUP with ISERROR. No need for macros.

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, 'Input'!$A$2:$A$x, 1, 0)), "", "X")`